# How can I access an Angular app hosted on IIS without the server name prefix?

Tags: angular, iis

I currently have an angular app hosted on IIS. It can be accessed by visiting "http://servername/appname" and works as expected. I am trying to set it up so that the hostname of the site works as a URL to access it. With .NET sites on the same IIS server, this works without a hitch.

How can this be configures to drop the servername prefix, and use a custom URL when accessing an Angular deployment.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to host the angular application in iis as site and set the site binding with hostname as shown below:

[image]

and bind the hostname with ip and the host file which is located at "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

```
72.30.35.10   example.com
```

and browse your site:

[image]